# Implement setValue in PCF Custom Control

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-component-framework

My custom control does not react to `getAttribute("abc").setValue("123")` from form js.

Do I have implement something in PCF Custom Control code?

Comment: My custom control does. Hard to tell why yours does not without you sharing any code. Please extend your question.

Comment: @skfd any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

Pls verify these.

1. Debug and see whether the `updateView()` in PCF `index.ts` is hitting, your control will be rendering there to get updated for any change in its property bag
2. Validate you have `usage="bound"` for the property in `ControlManifest.Input.xml` file